# My equation is not looking at a double

Tags: java, double, equation

I have an equation for calculating Heat Index. The teacher provided the equation and I copied it right but it is not looking at my humidity variable.(Sorry if I posted this wrong this is my first post on here)

```
public class HeatIndexCalculator {

  private int temperature;
  private double humidity;
  private double heatIndex;
  public double calculateHeatIndex(int currentTemp, double currentHumidity){
     temperature = currentTemp;
     humidity = (currentHumidity/100.0);
     heatIndex=(-42.379)+(2.04901523*temperature)+10.14333127*humidity+         
            -0.22475541*temperature*humidity+                                       
            -0.00683783*temperature*temperature+                                    
            -0.05481717*humidity*humidity+                                      
            0.00122874*temperature*temperature*humidity+                            
            0.00085282*temperature*humidity*humidity+                               
            -0.00000199*temperature*temperature*humidity*humidity;
```

Below is when I try to call to the method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x;
    double y,z;
    HeatIndexCalculator HeatC = new HeatIndexCalculator();
    System.out.println("Please enter a temperature in degrees Fahrenheit");
    x = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the current humidity as a percenage");
    y = input.nextDouble();
    z = HeatC.calculateHeatIndex(x, y);
   HeatC.printHeatIndex(x, y, z);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it is not looking at `humidity`?

Comment: We need to see where `humidity` is declared. If it's not being declared, it needs to be.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I will adjust my code so you can see it

Comment: @MiserableVariable When I called this method the output would be the same as long as the temperature was the same, but the humidity would be different

Comment: What are some test inputs and outputs you're using?

Comment: You should probably use proper code indentation. It is not cool or hip not to do so, and will get you into more trouble than you can imagine.

Comment: Your code looks ok. Tip: Simplify your equation, v.g. leave only the first line (comment the rest of it) for ease of verification. Check if changes to humidity affect to the value. If it does not, post here with a few examples and a more complete code (where do you write that value out?)

Comment: Some examples on input and output would be: temp-95 humidity-55 (supposed to come out with 108) result would be 90. I would do the same thing with humidity as 0 and I still get 90 as long as temp is 95.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your method. I expanded your code slightly to produce an executable example. The output is:

```
temperature=20 humidity=50 : -1.0736070574999943
temperature=20 humidity=25 : -2.601307430624994
temperature=20 humidity=75 : 0.44927371937500604
```

So it pays attention to humidity just fine. I suspect your problem is actually in your testing as you have two different units for humidity in use, one 100x larger than the other.

Comment: I don't see where there is two different units for humidity I use currentHumidity to bring in the value and then humidity for calulations.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works, but perhaps with not enought precision :

```
public static double calculateHeatIndex(int currentTemp, double currentHumidity)
{
    int temperature = currentTemp;
    double humidity = (currentHumidity);
    double heatIndex = (-42.379) + (2.04901523 * temperature) + 10.14333127 * humidity + -0.22475541 * temperature * humidity
            + -0.00683783 * temperature * temperature + -0.05481717 * humidity * humidity + 0.00122874 * temperature
            * temperature * humidity + 0.00085282 * temperature * humidity * humidity + -0.00000199 * temperature
            * temperature * humidity * humidity;
    return heatIndex;
}

@Test
public void testConst()
{
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(calculateHeatIndex(95, 55)));
}
```

Result :

```
108.94701570000008
```

Comment: The actual value is supposed to be 108.95. Have you tried it with differing humidity values?

Comment: I tried with 3 values from this [table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_index) and it's work

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was just looking at that as well. I am silly. Much appreciated!

Comment: Would you know how I make it round to the nearest hundredths place?

Comment: Math.round( value * 100.0 ) / 100.0; :-)